# getting Permission denied: '/vol/web/media' when trying to create file in my django application

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Here is my dockerfile.

```
    FROM python:3.9-alpine3.13
    
    ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
    
    COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
    COPY ./electron /electron
    COPY ./scripts /scripts
    
    WORKDIR /electron
    EXPOSE 8000
    
    RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps gcc musl-dev
    
    RUN python3.9 -m venv /py && \
        /py/bin/pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel && \
        apk add --update --no-cache postgresql-client && \
        apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .temp-deps \
            build-base postgresql-dev musl-dev linux-headers && \
        mkdir -p /vol/web/media && \ <----- The problem is located at this level
        /py/bin/pip install -r /requirements.txt && \
        adduser --disabled-password --no-create-home ozangue && \
        chown -R ozangue:ozangue /vol && \
        chmod -R 755 /vol && \
        chown -R ozangue:ozangue /vol/web/media && \
        chmod -R 755 /vol/web/media && \
        chmod -R +x /scripts
    
    ENV PATH="/scripts:/py/bin:$PATH"

USER ozangue

CMD ["run.sh"]
```

I cannot save a model containing a file. Because this file must be saved in /vol/web/media 
The part of the code that poses a problem is as follows (in views.py):

```
file = request.FILES["excel_file"]
file_obj = FileModelXSL(file=excel_file)
fichier_obj = fichier_obj.save()
```

in settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/static/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = '/vol/web/media'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (BASE_DIR / 'static',)
STATIC_ROOT = '/vol/web/static'
```

When I build the container, I don't get any errors but I have the impression that /vol/web/media: `mkdir -p /vol/web/media` is not created. But if it was not created the line `chmod -R 755 /vol/web/media` should have returned an error.
Need help please

part of docker-compose.yml relating to this container

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    container_name: ozangue
    build:
      context: .
    command: >
      python manage.py makemigrations --noinput &&
      python manage.py migrate --noinput && 
      python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - ./electron:/electron
      - ./data/web:/vol/web
```

Comment: Why do you think that?  When you run the container, are you using any sort of volume mount over these `/vol/...` directories?  (If so, the permissions of the host directory or named volume will override anything in the Dockerfile.)

Comment: I have volumes that I created from my docker-compose.yml file. Could this pose a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you mount `volumes:` into a container, the content of the host directory or named volume completely hides what was in the image before.

In your case, you're mounting `./data/web` over `/vol/web` in the image.  That means that the `mkdir /vol/web/media` in the Dockerfile gets hidden: whether or not there is a `media` directory, and which user owns it, completely depends on the contents of the `./data/web` directory on the host.

If you can delete these `volumes:`, that's the best solution.  For example, you do not need a volume mount hiding the image's `/electron` directory since that code is already `COPY`ed into the image.

Otherwise you need to make sure the directory exists *on the host*

```bash
mkdir ./data/web/static ./data/web/media
```

To make the directory writable from inside the container you need to figure out what numeric user ID owns the directory.  Usually it is your current user, and `id -u` will tell you its numeric uid.  In your Compose file, you need to set `user:` to that numeric uid.  You do not specifically need to "create the user" and it's not a good practice to embed the uid in the Dockerfile.

```yaml
user: '1000'
```

Comment: If I delete volumes: from docker-compose file it will no longer be possible for me to persist the uploaded files in the container on my host. I am wrong ?

Comment: Is the COPY command reversible? When I write COPY sourcefile recipientfile, by uploading a file to recipientfile, this file is automatically created in sourcefile

Comment: Right, without `volumes:` anything you change in the container-temporary filesystem will be lost.  But your application really shouldn't be modifying its own source code, which is why I suggest deleting the `/electron` mount.  Often a good setup is to not have `volumes:` at all and arrange for persistent data to be stored somewhere else like a database (though it seems like that might not work for your specific case).